# Why Is It That Meta WebApp Rep Is Linked To WebApp Rep?

Tags: discussion, meta

I find it strange that my meta webapp and webpp reputation are linked to each other. Don't you think that the ability to discuss meta topics is completely different from the ability to provide good answers to solid questions?

Answer (score 6):

A few reasons... at least this is the current thinking:

- The more you participate on webapps, the more "stake" you should have in how the site is governed and run here on meta.
- Since votes on meta no longer "hurt" or "harm" for reputation people are more free to cast votes on the content of posts, without worrying about the effect on the poster's rep.
- The focus should be on participation on *the parent site*; participation on meta should never become a rep-generating goal in and of itself.

I plan to blog about this soon, but that's the gist of it.

Comment: Is there any plans of implementing this on other metas - mainly meta.SO?

Comment: @Amarghosh: I would be very much against this. Meta.SO has grown into a corporate site, more about the products, activities, and philosophy of Stack Overflow Inc. Only a very small component of meta.SO is the literal support of stackoverflow.com. The reputation between meta.SO and SO.com  should not be linked in that manner because the audience of the two sites (meta.SO and SO.com) are not as inseparably linked as, say, meta.webapps and webapps.com. You don't have the same overlap of audience and purpose. Bad idea.

Comment: @Robert fair enough. I was just asking.